# Seting popupWinodw's background makes all avctivies' backgrounds became translucent

Tags: android, android-layout

The problem is that after I show the popup window, all of the activities' background(color: #fff) became translucent.When I change a background to other color(#f0f or else), it will not become translucent.
 And when I debug, it will not become translucent too.
 And the translucent effect will changes with the alpha value. ex. when I change the setAlpha(50) to setAlpha(150) the translucent effect will change, which seems that there is some relation between background color of the popupWindow's contentView and the other activities'.

My code is below.

```
popup = PopWin.popupWindow(context, TestActivity.this, popid);
View contentView = popup.getContentView();
contentView.getBackground().setAlpha(50);

public static PopupWindow popupWindow(final Context context,
        final View view, int rsid) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View popView = inflater.inflate(rsid, null, false);
    final PopupWindow popWin = new PopupWindow(popView,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, true);

    popWin.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
    popWin.setFocusable(true);

    popWin.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    return popWin;
}
```

The image below is the screenshot when became translucent.(I can not upload image, sorry!)

http://g.hiphotos.baidu.com/zhidao/pic/item/aec379310a55b3191df0b28343a98226cffc173e.jpg

All the gray/black areas is white(#fff) in correct state.